# How to disable error goldbars in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Since the last update, i'm getting spammed by errors like:

> Feature 'Semantic classification' is currently unavailable due to an internal error.

from the goldbars of Visual Studio.

It does not create any other problems, but it becomes **really** annoying.

[image]